# Add "Show All' to the bottom of a list for Jquery Custom Autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, autocomplete

How do I create a link at the bottom of a Autocomplete that has categories? Ly MVC application shows selections and categories via textbox using jQuery's autocomplete & catcomplete

I want to show "Show All" at the bottom of my list that will essentially click the search button with an empty string text box. (the search button functions are already implemented, and searching string empty returns all

so

1. What is the jQuery snippet to append "show all" to the bottom of the list.?
2. On item select, fire click searchbutton function?
3. On item select "Select All", set value of search box to "" and click search?

   ```
   public class SearchCriteria
   {
       public string label { get; set; }
       public string category { get; set; }
   }

   <label for="search">Search: </label>
   <input id="search">

   <script>
   $.widget("custom.catcomplete", $.ui.autocomplete, 
   {
   _renderMenu: function (ul, items)
   {
       var that = this,
       currentCategory = "";
       $.each(items, function (index, item)
       {
           if (item.category != currentCategory)
           {
               ul.append("<li class='ui-autocomplete-category'>" + item.category + "</li>");
               currentCategory = item.category;
           }
           that._renderItemData(ul, item);
       });
   }

   });

   $(function () {
   $("#search").catcomplete({
       delay: 0,
       source: '@Url.Action("AutoComplete", "Search")'
   });
   });
   </script>
   ```

Comment: added this jquery snippet after renderItemData but it does not work. `return $( "<li></li>" )
           .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
           .append( "<a><span class='" + item.status + "'></span>" + item.value + "</a>" )
        .appendTo( ul );`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer for anyone that needs an autocomplete with:

- Minimum length (look for minChars)
- Source binding (List) (look for source: '@Url.Action...)
- Seperated into categories (look for "custom.catcomplete")
- "Search All" added to the bottom of the autocomplete list.(look for  $('.ui-autocomplete').append)

HTML:

```
<label for="search">Search: </label>
<input id="search">
```

JS:

```
<script>
$.widget("custom.catcomplete", $.ui.autocomplete, {

    _renderMenu: function (ul, items)
    {
        var that = this,
        currentCategory = "";
        $.each(items, function (index, item)
        {
            if (item.category != currentCategory)
            {
                ul.append("<li class='ui-autocomplete-category'>" + item.category + "</li>");
                currentCategory = item.category;
            }
            that._renderItemData(ul, item);
        });
    }

 });
</script>

<script>
$(function () {
    $("#search").catcomplete({
        delay: 0,
        minChars: 3,
        source: '@Url.Action("AutoComplete", "Search")',

        open: function (event, ul) {
            $('.ui-autocomplete').append('<li><b><a href="javascript:alert(\'redirecting...\')">See All Result</b></a></li>'); //See all results
     },

     focus: function (event, ul) {
       $( "#search" ).val( ui.item.value );
       return false;
     },

   select: function (event, ul) {
       $("#search").val(ul.item.value);
          return false;
      }

    });
});
</script>
```